# Spring-MVC best practices: Why put transactions on services rather than DAOs?

Tags: java, transactions, spring-mvc

I am learning Spring-MVC in my first project here.

After reading the documentation on transactions I noted that **all of the examples put transactions around the service objects/methods**, not the DAO (data access objects/methods).

I wondered why. Without knowing better I would think to **add transactions around most of my DAO methods** that access the database (my thinking: database=transactions). I don't yet have many service methods that span multiple DAO's (but I guess that could be a reason for marking services as transactional).

**The question:**
I just want to know what others do in this situation. Do you naturally put transactions around the lowest level item that you can (e.g. around DAOs always, and around services only when they span multiple DAO's in a way which requires transactions)?

Or do you just focus on transactions around services as a general principal? Thus sticking to one layer because that's more all-encompassing in the long run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For my money I try the put the transaction at the coarsest point possible in the app, this tends to be a service/manager like object that coordinates calls to one or more finer gained dao calls.

In theory you could put transactions everywhere from services to daos, assuming they are defined to join an existing transaction if required. In practice I've found this less than useful as it is unnecessary and will just annoy you when attempting to debug the code.

Answer (score 2):

This is done so that the data that you have selected/queried from the DataSource remains valid while you are processing on the data.

In other case (putting transactions on DAO) the data can be changed while you are processing on the data and might get wrong results.

Comment: The question isn't so much whether or not to use transactions, clearly they are necessary for the reasons you stated. The question is whether to apply Spring-MVC transactions to the service layer, DAO layer, or a combination of the two.

Comment: My point is to have transactions on Service Layer unless you are exposing DAO Layer to be called by layers above the Service Layer. As I said if you have transactions at DAO Layer when will you release/close i.e., commit the transaction? In case of a Service Layer you clearly know that you are done with your processing and should commit the transaction.

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you for the quick clarification. So, in general you say it's safer to stick to the service layer essentially, in my words, "to be safe".

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are right, but to add color to the answers: the transaction goes at the service layer should encapsulate an atomic piece of business logic. Since this business logic should stand alone without interference from other business logic, the transactions need to be at the service layer.